# Andrica's conjecture implies Legendre's conjecture

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Does Andrica's conjecture imply Legendre's conjecture? I have the following reasoning.

Let $p_n$ denote the $n$th prime. Recall that Andrica's conjecture is the following statement:
$$
\sqrt{p_{n+1}}-\sqrt{p_n}<1,
$$

for all positive nonzero integer $n$. On the other hand, Legendre's conjecture states that there is a prime number between $m^2$ and $(m+1)^2$ for every positive integer $m$. I then propose the following Theorem.

**Theorem 1**. Andrica's conjecture implies Legendre's conjecture.

*Proof*. Let $g_n$ denote the $n$th prime gap. Following Andrica's conjecture, we have $g_{n}<2{\sqrt  {p_{n}}}+1$, or equivalently $p_{n+1}<2{\sqrt  {p_{n}}}+1+p_{n}$.

Now let $N$ be a positive integer greater than $2$ and $p_{n}$ the greatest prime smaller than or equal to $(N-1)^2$. We then have:

\begin{align*}
(N-1)^2 & < p_{n+1}\\
        & < 2{\sqrt  {p_{n}}}+1+p_{n} \\
        & < (\sqrt  {p_{n}} + 1)^2.
\end{align*}

But since $p_{n}<(N-1)^2<p_{n+1}$, we have:
\begin{align*}
(N-1)^2 & < (\sqrt  {p_{n}} + 1)^2 \\
        & < (\sqrt  {(N-1)^2} + 1)^2 \\
        & < (N-1+1)^2 \\
        & < N^2.
\end{align*}

We have therefore shown that assuming Andrica's conjecture, $(N-1)^2<p_{n+1}<N^2$, i.e., that there is always a prime between $(N-1)^2$ and $N^2$ for all positive integer $N>2$.
$$\tag*{$\square$}$$

I recall reading somewhere that one can not imply Legendre's conjecture from Andrica's, so I must be missing something here. What is it?

Comment: You have a typo, "But since $p_n < p_{n+1} < (N-1)^2$" ought to be "But since $p_n < (N-1)^2 < p_{n+1}$", and after that you forgot to mention $p_{n+1}$ so you just state $(N-1)^2 < N^2$. Should be $(N-1)^2 < p_{n+1} < (\sqrt{p_n} + 1)^2$ etc. Yes, Andrica's conjecture implies Legendre's conjecture.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you, typos corrected. If you post an answer I will accept it.

Comment: So that means Legendre's conjecture is true for twin primes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Indeed, the truth of Andrica's conjecture implies the truth of Legendre's conjecture, and your proof is correct.

As a matter of style, it is not good that you switch from $m^2$ and $(m+1)^2$ used in the statement of Legendre's conjecture to using $(N-1)^2$ and $N^2$ in the proof, it would be better to use the same notation in both. And I would leave the prime gap $g_n$ out of it and write

\begin{align}
(N-1)^2 &< p_{n+1} \\
&= (\sqrt{p_{n+1}})^2 \\
&< (\sqrt{p_n} + 1)^2 \tag{Andrica's conjecture}\\
&\leqslant \bigl((N-1) + 1\bigr)^2 \tag{$p_n \leqslant (N-1)^2$}\\
&= N^2\,.
\end{align}

But the latter is a matter of taste.